# Поиск в векторе по нескольким параметрам

Tags: c++, поиск, stl

Подскажите, есть есть контейнер объектов, которые содержат несколько параметров, например:

```
struct CMyData
{
    int m_age;
    bool m_isMale;
    std::string m_Name;
}

std::vector<CMyData> data;
```

и мне надо найти в нем объект, с самым большим возрастом, а при равном возрасте мужского пола, а при одинаковом поле с именем которое начинается ближе к 'А'

понятно, если бы мне надо было отсортировать контейнер, но мне не нужна сортировка, мне нужен именно однократный **поиск**

подскажите, можно ли это сделать красиво/компактно (я о коде) и при этом быстро

или придется делать по старинке типа `for` по всем элементам и сравнивать с ранее найденным элементом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью стандартных алгоритмов это можно сделать относительно красиво, но по скорости от обычного цикла `for` это отличаться не должно.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const CMyData &a, const CMyData &b)
{
    // В третьем аргументе `a` и `b` поменял местами специально.
    return std::tie(a.m_age, a.m_isMale, b.m_Name) < std::tie(b.m_age, b.m_isMale, a.m_Name);
});
```

Такая конструкция возвращает итератор на нужный элемент. Если нужна ссылка на элемент, то `*std::max_element(...)`.

Comment: спасибо, а уточню - просадки в скорости вообще нет, компилятор такой код приведет к коду, который был бы написан в лоб?

Comment: Я не думаю, возможно просто алгоритмы stl работают достаточно быстро

Comment: @Zhihar Единственный способ узнать наверняка - дизассемблировать оба варианта и сравнить (https://gcc.godbolt.org/ в помощь). Желательно проверить с разными настройками оптимизации, на разных компиляторах. Знать ассемблер для этого не обязательно - обычно в каком варианте инструкций меньше, тот и лучше.

Comment: Если не сортировать исходные данные то асимптотически быстрее линейного поиска ничего не получится ( не важно как вы его напишите - в лоб самостоятельно или с использованием алгоритмов  из stl). Для однократного поиска действительно быстрее всего будет пройтись один раз по массиву. Если поисков (запросов) много, то правильнее будет отсортировать массив и использовать бинарный поиск.